# what situation will throw exception "scala.util.control.BreakControl"?

Tags: scala

My code throw **exception** `scala.util.control.BreakControl`, but I don't know why. Does anyone know?

[image]

Some place I use `breakable` and `break`, but I don't why cause this exception.

**fragment 1**

```
breakable {
                for (quaOfLine <- dataOfLine) {
                    try {
                        // ...   some other code

                        if (judgeTime(jsonQua.getInt("startTime")) == judgeTime(jsonLine.getInt("startTime"))) {

                           // ... some other code
                            if (quaRRIDs.length / RRIDs.length.toFloat >= 0.8 || quaRRIDs.length / RRIDs.length.toFloat <= 1.2) {
                                var count = 0
                                breakable {
                                    for (rrid <- RRIDs) {
                                        for (quaRRID <- quaRRIDs) {
                                            if (rrid == quaRRID) {
                                                count += 1
                                                break                   //break
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (count / RRIDs.length.toFloat >= 0.8) {
                                    sameLine = qualifier + "::" + value
                                    break           // break
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace
                    }
                }
            }
```

**fragment 2**

```
breakable {
                for (quaOfDest <- dataOfDest) {
                    try {
                        val qualifier = quaOfDest.getString("qualifier")
                        val value = quaOfDest.getString("value")
                        val jsonQua = new JSONObject(value)


                        val (quaSLon, quaSLat, quaELon, quaELat) = getSELonLat(jsonQua)

                        if (jsonQua.getInt("timeBucket").toString == judgeTime(jsonLine.getInt("startTime"))) {

                            someDest = qualifier + "::" + value
                            break     //break
                        }
                    } catch {
                        case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you show your code (and the full stacktrace)?

Comment: @Thilo I update the question, can you see again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`scala.util.control.BreakControl` is thrown by the method `scala.util.control.Breaks.break`. It is used for simulating the `break` statement from Java. It is used like this:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks.{break, breakable}

breakable {
  for(i <- 1 until 10) {
    println(i)
    if(i > 5) break
  }
}
```

`BreakControl` is a private class so normally it won't be thrown by anything else than `break`.

This also means that inside a `breakable` block you shouldn't catch `BreakControl` yourself. You `break` inside a `try` block and then catch all `Throwables` and print them. `BreakControl` is a `Throwable` so it will be caught by you instead of by the `breakable` method.

If you really want to catch all `Exceptions`/`Throwables`, you should do something like this:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks.{break, breakable}
import scala.util.control.ControlThrowable

breakable {
  for(i <- 1 until 10) {
    try {
      println(i)
      if(i > 5) break
    } catch {
      case c: ControlThrowable => throw c
      case t: Throwable => t.printStackTrace
    }
  }
}
```

The Scala Standard Library also includes a special construct for cases like this which lets you catch all `Throwables` except for fatal ones like `OutOfMemoryError` or `StackOverflowError`, and also everything that extends `ControlThrowable`:

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

try {
  //do stuff
} catch {
  case NonFatal(e) => e.printStackTrace
}
```

Comment: I got it! Thank you for your help!