# Python - Returning a break statement

Tags: python, loops

If you call a function to check exit conditions, can you have it return a break statement? Something like:

```
def check():
    return break

def myLoop:
    while myLoop:
        check()
```

Is there anything like this allowed? I know the syntax as written isn't valid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that unfortunately. You would have to check the return value and then decide to break out of the loop in the caller.

```
while myLoop:
   result = check()
   if result == 'oh no':
       break
```

Of course, depending on what you are trying to do, it may just be as simple as:

```
result = check()
while result != 'oh no':
     result = check()
```

Answer (score 2):

`break` is a keyword but not an object so it is treated differently by the interpreter, [link](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement). Python function can only return objects or the like.

If you want to break out of a loop when deep inside functions, one way is to use an exception:

```
class BreakException(Exception):
    pass
```

Raise the exception somewhere in a function:

```
def some_func():
    raise BreakException()
```

And you can break out of a loop like this:

```
try:
    while True:
        some_func()
except BreakException:
    pass
```

I do not feel this is good practice, but have seen some language using it, Scala for example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919910/what-situation-will-throw-exception-scala-util-control-breakcontrol/37920766).

Comment: Oh, that's good to know. It definitely does seem a bit dangerous, but I'll keep it in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
def check():
    #define your conditions here with if..else statement 
    return True


def myLoop():
    while True:
        if check()==True: break
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?